# Marge yAxis column's cells vertically in highcharts gantt

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gvaartjes/4g7ekw65/), and I want to merge vertically some of the first column's cells. in this example, I want to merge the 0, 1, 2 cells in the first column.

How is it possible?

Code of the example:

```
 yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    grid: {      
      borderColor: '#3a5d96',      
      columns: [{
        title: {
          text: 'Tasks',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        }
      }, {
        title: {
          text: 'Assignee',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        },
        labels: {
          format: '{point.assignee}'
        }
      }, {
        title: {
          text: 'Duration',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point,
              days = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
              number = (point.end - point.start) / days;
            return Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that vertically merging options doesn't exist for the columns treegrid in the Highcharts Gantt, however you can hide those paths between the labels.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/va1fqwd5/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this,
          ticks = chart.yAxis[0].treeGrid.axis.grid.columns[1].ticks;


        ticks[0].mark.hide();
        ticks[1].mark.hide();
        ticks[2].mark.hide();
      }
    }
  },
```